# If the cup is dropped so it falls freely, will the water continue to flow from the holes? Bernoulli's Principle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, pressure, bernoulli-equation

A tall Styrofoam cup is filled with water. Two holes are punched in the cup near the bottom, and water begins rushing out. If the cup is dropped so it falls freely, will the water continue to flow from the holes? Explain using Bernoulli's Principle.

Answer (score 2):

Water flow through holes in the cup depends on pressure drop through the holes.  That pressure drop is the difference between the water pressure on the bottom of the cup and atmospheric pressure.  The pressure on the bottom of the cup before the cup is dropped is $P=\rho g h$, where $h$ is the height of the water in the cup.  When the cup is in free fall, the value of $g$ is effectively 0, so there is no pressure drop across the holes in the cup when it is in free fall, meaning that there is no flow through the holes in the cup when it is in free fall.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgwiDDBrizc  for experiment

Answer (score 1):

The water flow through the holes will initially stop after the cup is dropped for the reasons given in the @DavidWhite answer.  As the cup speeds up, however, Bernoulli forces will start to pull the water out through the holes.  At first these forces will be counteracted by surface tension but eventually the Bernoulli force will win and water will resume flowing through the holes.  The speed at which this occurs will depend on the size of the holes, with smaller holes requiring higher speed.  The shape of the cup will also play a role.

Comment: I don't think this is correct: it isn't surface tension that causes the water to stop flowing, but -- as @DavidWhite points out -- the fact that there isn't a pressure drop across the holes. This can be seen using the Equivalence principle, here's a [entertaining segment with Brian Greene](https://youtu.be/0jjFjC30-4A?t=253) on Colbert.

Comment: @Phillip David White is correct as far as he goes, but my point is that Bernoulli forces will cause the flow to resume once a certain speed is reached.  The speed at which this occurs will depend on the surface tension.  I'll edit my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: I am confused. The speed for the Bernoulli effect should be  relative to the container, not to the earth? Since relative to the container there is no water flow, how can one have a Bernoulli effect? Mind you it is the first time I looke at this, here   http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pber.html

Comment: @annav It is the speed relative to the air that matters. I assume that inside the cup the pressure will be normal atmospheric while outside it will be less due to the airspeed.